# Is it dangerous to change or remove company-brand boot logo?

Tags: boot-animation

There are two types of boot animation:

1. Company-brand logo
2. ROM-based

I was able to change ROM-based animation by rooting the phone and using a custom ROM.

However, I'm a bit confused about how to change or remove the brand logo animation. Is it safe to do that? Will it increase the speed of the booting process?

Comment: Depends on device. I know it's very easy on the HTC One M7 as the bootloader image is stored in its very own partition. I love the space/planet earth one off some XDA thread, they all come in flashable zips.

Comment: I've Xiaomi Mi4i with Cyanogenmod 13.0 (6.0.1) @AaronGillion

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have a very different take on this matter than @sbrm1. Note a few things first and then decide whether doing this is worth it:

- The *boot logo* is a actually a raw binary image, constrained by size, not format.
- The format of the bootloader splash screen, as it is known, varies for even models of the same device (case in point, Exynos and Qualcomm Samsung Galaxy models).
- On Qualcomm devices, the bootloader splash logo is typically stored on a partition called `splash` or `logo`, to change which you need to flash as similarly named `.mbn` or `.bin` file (not `.img`)
- If you don't choose a logo with a format and size specific to your device, it may result in unforeseen circumstances (read, what will appear to be a **Hard Brick**, the device not booting up at all). Why? The bootloader is dumb and will try to load whatever is on the splash partition as long as it fits in there (i.e., has a specific size). It might not even be a picture at all. The bootloader may choose to 'panic', i.e., show some error message and reboot, keep trying to reload the splash, or continue booting the OS. You can hope for the last, but you never know unless someone has documented the specific behaviour for your device or you learn it the hard way. You may or may not lose your charging screen, however.
- Do you still want to do this? I don't know of a guide specific to your device, let that put you off a bit. If there is indeed an acceptable splash file for your device, just `fastboot flash` the image file (note, *image* as in *disk image*, not *photograph*) to whichever of the above 2 mentioned splash partitions which exists on your device. This can be done on some HTC, LG and Nexus devices with Qualcomm or Tegra chipsets.
- A last FYI, the manufacturer may choose to integrate the logo into the bootloader (`aboot`). I know Xiaomi does this for some devices (Redmi 1s and Redmi 2 - personal experience), it's probably true in your case too. Then you will need a **custom bootloader**, with the splash screen packed into the bootloader flashable image file (*image* as above).

Still there? I can't help you beyond discouraging you, so...

Comment: @sbrm1 You, in simple terms, just were very careful or got very lucky. Not something we can or should assume is true for the OP. Also, in doing something inherently risky like this, you should always disclose what may possibly happen even if you yourself have never experienced it.

Comment: @sbrm1, Please let me know of these apps you talk about. I would think that these apps do barely more than changing the boot animation, not the boot logo.

Comment: I checked and found that my answer is applicable only for other devices with the same chipset (or in the case of Mediatek, any other Mediatek SoC)... I'm updating my answer.

Comment: @sbrm1 please quote sources where you found this information.

Answer (score 8):

Yes it is possible to change the company logo. If you have ever flashed a custom ROM which changes it and still have the `update.zip` file lying around, sometimes (after extraction) you will find a logo.bin (its a *raw* Binary file) file in the root directory. This file contains the Brand Logo as well as the charging animation and the image to be displayed in fastboot mode. However on your phone (and most other phones) there is no logo.bin file but just a partition named `LOGO` where a complete dump of the logo.bin file is saved.

There are `update.zips` just for changing your phone branding, however only files for the correct resolution and chipset will display correctly. (Yes, you can indeed use such files made for other phones with the same SoC with the same resolution)

Comment: I strongly disagree with the steps you have suggested to enable changing the bootloader logo. The chipsets in the Mi4i and the OPO are vastly different (64-bit vs. 32-bit architecture and bootloaders to say the least), and this may hard-brick the OP's phone. Bottom line is: Bootloader logo has got nothing to do with resolution. It depends on bootloader, binary format and image size. Also, our policy is to reproduce critical linked content in case the link ever goes down.

Comment: Also, *RAW* binary and *raw* binary are 2 different things in the world of digital images. The 1st is related to unprocessed photos and the other is what you probably intend. -1 for ill-advised recommendations.

Comment: @TamoghnaChowdhury fixed the raw part.